# Text won't wrap/break withing div or paragraph

Tags: html, css

I'm having a noob issue. I have a long string of text (with spaces) within a `<p>` tag.

The string just goes on forever, and won't wrap or break at the end. Here's what I have going on:

http://jsfiddle.net/lordzardeck/RmFkk/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you're being affected by the style at ext-all.css (line:21)

```
.x-grid-cell-inner { white-space: nowrap; }
```

You'll probably want to do something like:

```
.chat-message p { white-space:normal; }
```

Comment: ok, i set it to normal, but now the text wraps around the image. I want to stay flush with the username. or should that be a separate question?

Comment: how about a .chat-message p { white-space:normal; padding-left:64px; }